# What exactly tensorflow.gather() does?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

I saw code for triplet loss that contains the function tf.gather(). What this function does?

I have gone through the tensorflow's official website for definition but still unable to get it.

```
def margin_triplet_loss(y_true, y_pred, margin, batch_size):
    anchor = tf.gather(y_pred, tf.range(0, batch_size, 3))
    positive = tf.gather(y_pred, tf.range(1, batch_size, 3))
    negative = tf.gather(y_pred, tf.range(2, batch_size, 3))

    loss = K.maximum(margin
                 + K.sum(K.square(anchor-positive), axis=1)
                 - K.sum(K.square(anchor-negative), axis=1),
                 0.0)
    return K.mean(loss)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tf.gather is a function to index an array. You gather the elements which you specify by the index argument. This is not natively posible for tensorflow tensors.

tf.gather(y_pred, tf.range(0, batch_size, 3)) is equivalent in numpy to y_pred[0:batch_size:3], which means that you return every third element starting from the first one.

Comment: Correct, just note that `y_pred[0:batch_size:3]` could also be used in TensorFlow in this case, and would be faster too.